# jQuery $.when().done() equivalent without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do the equivalent of the following in Vanilla JS or Javascript, but I can't figure out how:

```
$.when( { testing: 123 } ).done(function( x ) {
  alert( x.testing ); // Alerts "123"
});
```

Is there any equivalent of this in Vanilla JS or Javascript? What is the syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`done` is a method belonging to jQuery `Deferred` objects which don't exist in VanillaJS.

You could try simply creating a synchronous promise:

```js
Promise.resolve({testing: 123}).then(function(x) {
  alert(x.testing);
});
```

EDIT: You will need a [polyfill for Internet Explorer](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/es6-promise).